# Getting Permission error:Created a virtual directory for which the physical path is from the shared folder of other PC

Tags: iis, iis-7, virtual-directory

I am facing an issue when i created a virtual directory and mapped it to the physical path of the folder shared on the network by other PC which have provided full control to everyone on the the network Read/Write.

When I tried to open the folder on the network via URL using virtual directory, it gives an error:

> configuration issue you may not have permission to access this file.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access mapped drive by IIS running asp.net mvc web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412669/access-mapped-drive-by-iis-running-asp-net-mvc-web-application)