# Unable to access mounted NFS drive from IIS web application

Tags: iis, nfs, mapped-drive

We are having an issue with accessing locally mapped NFS drives from IIS Web application(Win 2012 Server).

Storage device(Based on Debian) is in local network and we have configured NFS folder(suppose it is "\storage\data\Folder") and mapped it to a server assigning drive letter X:\ after installing NFS client.

When ever we mention the full path("\storage\data\Folder") it works fine. When we address the share folder as "\storage\data\Folder" it works, but if its x:\ then it returns error as "Application error Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation".

**Things as they are now:**

-No restriction configured in NAS.

-Sub folders and files inside mapped drives are accessible for user.

-Not getting security tab while taking [Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJKbm.png) of X drive(Not sure it's how it should be)

We have tried by change the application Pool identity to administrator ID and tested but still got error.

Much appreciated if anyone could suggest some solutions to this.

Comment: IIS does not support mapped drives, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/257174/using-mapped-drives-with-iis

Comment: as lex li suggest there is no concept of a 'mapped' drive in IIS. you could try to use application pool identity to network service. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412669/access-mapped-drive-by-iis-running-asp-net-mvc-web-application