# Mapped Azure File Share not accessible from PHP on Windows Azure VM

Tags: php, windows, azure, iis

I have a Windows Azure VM running IIS/PHP. I have mapped an Azure file share to the VM. PHP always returns false when running is_dir('//server/share'). How can I map the Azure file share so that PHP can see it?

Comment: when I run PSEXEC and mount the drive under SYSTEM account the drive shows up in PHP but says username and password incorrect. In Windows Explorer, the drive shows as disconnected but still works when clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get PHP to see the mapped drive by adding the Azure storage account as an admin user on the server and using that account to connect as under basic settings for the web site under IIS.

See: [Access mapped drive by IIS running asp.net mvc web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412669/access-mapped-drive-by-iis-running-asp-net-mvc-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

Kishan Gupta's instructions from the above [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412669/access-mapped-drive-by-iis-running-asp-net-mvc-web-application) worked for me but only after I removed the mapped drive that was added previously using the script from Azure portal, and specifying "connect using different credentials" when mapping the drive. PS: Not enough reps to comment, so had to add this as an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34933449)