# Django-App: IIS Permission for Network Harddrive

Tags: django, iis

I have a Django app that displays files in a folder via "os.listdir" in my Django app.

However, the files are on a network hard drive with the drive letter "W".

When I start Django as a development environment, this also works.

I have deployed Django via IIS but due to lack of permissions, presumably these files cannot be displayed. I then added the user "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" in the "Security" tab for the entire hard drive for testing with "Full Access" but still my Django app cannot read this folder on the external hard drive.

Which user rights do I have to set so that Django can access a network hard disk via IIS to read data there?

Comment: Mapped drives are not supported by IIS at all. You have to use UNC paths and also switch the application pool identity from the local account "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" to a network account (such as a domain account that has access to the files).

Comment: Yep, the community member has said. You can only do it by using UNC paths. You could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412669/access-mapped-drive-by-iis-running-asp-net-mvc-web-application) for details.